# How to restrict access to only one Contribution Page

Tags: forms, contribution-page

Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 4.5.8
Working on a site which has several contribution pages.  We want to leave the majority of them accessible to anonymous users, but have just one that we want to restrict to "members-only".

In Drupal the $form variable passed in hook_form_alter() will have a '#access' parameter that can be set to false.

What's the best way to accomplish this with a CiviCRM form? 
Is there something that can be modified in the $form variable using hook_civicrm_buildForm()?

Some better way?

Comment: How is "members-only" defined here?  Is it folks with a current CiviMember record?

Comment: "Members Only" is based on Drupal user role, I want to know more generally how to programmatically deny access to a single contribution page

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty drupal-ly way of doing it, but I still wonder about a CiviCRM specific methodology.

```
function civicrm_custom_access_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  global $user;

  $grant_access = 0;
  foreach($user->roles as $key => $role_name) {
    if($key == 3 || $key == 5 || $key == 4 || $key == 6 || $key == 7) {
      $grant_access = 1;
    } 
  }

  if($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main' && $form->_id == 2 && !$grant_access) {
    drupal_access_denied();
    drupal_exit();
  }

}
```

Comment: +1 for this approach, which since it uses hooks could also be done in a CiviCRM extension. Pretty much what I was going to suggest - intercept in hook_civicrm_buildForm(), deny access if user access conditions aren't met.

Comment: Sorry if this is a really stupid question -- but where would this code snippet be placed?

Comment: this bit of code implements hook_civicrm_buildForm().http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm.....In this example my module name was civicrm_custom_access ....So place this bit of code in a small module...with the function name YOUR_MODULE_NAME_civicrm_buildForm()